# GMP mpz_t return type for function

Tags: c, return-type, gmp

I am trying to have a recursive function that will eventually return an mpz_t data type. I have tried to implement this using `mpz_get_ui()` but this fails to give the correct result with very large numbers (15 digits +). The purpose of the program is cryptography.

I have also tried making the function of type void and adding an mpz_t parameter that acts as an answer placeholder like so: `void fme(mpz_t y, mpz_t g, mpz_t x, mpz_t p)` but this eliminates the possibility of recursively calling the function as it no longer returns anything.

I was wondering if anything cna be done with an mpz_t pointer data type `mpz_t*`?

This is what I have thus far:

```
unsigned long int fme(mpz_t g, mpz_t x, mpz_t p) {

  mpz_t result, temp;
  mpz_init(result);
  mpz_init(temp);

  if (mpz_cmp_d(x, 0) == 0) {

    mpz_clear(result);
    mpz_clear(temp);
    return 1;
  } else if (mpz_even_p(x) != 0) {

    mpz_fdiv_q_ui(temp, x, 2);
    mpz_set_ui(result, fme(g, temp, p));
    mpz_mul(result, result, result);
    mpz_mod(result, result, p);

    unsigned long int answer = mpz_get_ui(result);
    mpz_clear(result);
    mpz_clear(temp);
    return answer;
  }
```

Comment: Why not just return `mpz_t`??

Comment: It is of array_type. C does not allow this.

Comment: Och sure. `but this eliminates the possibility of recursive` is false.

Comment: I thought about simply calling it on its own but the result that fme() would eventually return is what I need to use in the parenthesys. Not one of its variables. If any suggestions on how that can be done would be perfect! I would like to keep it as close to this structure as possible.

Comment: Note that it's unclear what you function returns if both `if` conditions are false.

Comment: When it was an `unsigned long int`, I simply returned -1 which I checked against afterwards but that is not important.

Answer (score 0):

I think just:

```
// note: places result in the first argument, that has to initialized
void fme(mpz_t result, mpz_t g, mpz_t x, mpz_t p) {
    if (mpz_cmp_d(x, 0) == 0) {
         mpz_set_ui(result, 1);
         return;
    } else if (mpz_even_p(x) != 0) {
         mpz_t temp;
         mpz_init(temp);
         mpz_fdiv_q_ui(temp, x, 2);
         fme(result, g, temp, p);
         mpz_clear(temp);

         mpz_mul(result, result, result);
         mpz_mod(result, result, p);
    }
}

// should work the same as original
unsigned long int fme_old(mpz_t g, mpz_t x, mpz_t p) {
    mpz_t result;
    mpz_init(result);
    fme(result, g, x, p);
    unsigned long int ret = mpz_get_ui(result);
    mpz_clear(result);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I will try this right now and come back with feedback. By the way, I am assuming that when you recursively call your function you meant fme2?

EDIT: Nevermind you fixed it :)

Comment: I have tried your suggested code, I have refactored my code so it suits the new way of 'returning' the answer but it appears that it does not return what I expected. In any of the fme() occurences in my program.

EDIT: I was not clear enough, The instances that use fme(result, g, x, p) I later on continue to do mpz_set(var, result) <--- but this usually returns 0.